# MIPS variable offset

Tags: mips, offset

I'm making a code that searches and finds these characters (aeiou) from another string and saves all other characters (max 3). If there aren't 3 different characters from (aeiou), it must take those one.
For example I have this string: "rossi". I want compare every single character of this string with the other string and find those different.
I thought like this: 
`if "r" is different from "a" && "e" && "i" && "o" && "u" then` save "r" in a register and take the second character to compare.

I wrote this but I can't exit from loop

```
       .data 0x10010000
cognome:    .asciiz "rossi"
voc:        .asciiz "aeiou"

        .text 0x400000
main:   la $s0, cognome     
        la $s1, voc         

cerca:  lbu $t0, 0($s0)             

sc_voc: lbu $t1, 0($s1)             
        bne $t0, $t1, sc_voc        
        move $s3, $t2
        j cerca
```

I know this is wrong but I don't know how to increment the offset of lbu because this take the first one

Can you help me?

Comment: Just add 1 to `$s1`. It's really the only way you can do this, as MIPS has no variable offsetting or post-increment operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are stuck in that loop because you only compare the letter 'r' to the letter 'a' to see if they are equal.  You have to work your way through the character arrays that you have created.  One thing that you can do is take advantage of the fact that when you define a string using `.asciiz`, the assembler automatically appends the null terminator.  This allows you to work through the problem with the following pseudo-code:

```
place starting address of cognome in $s0
place starting address of voc in $s1
place starting address of storage in $s3
initialize an index for cognome ($t3 = 0)
initialize an index for voc ($t4 = 0)
initialize an index for storage ($t5 = 0)

LOOP1
if (current value stored at cognome index does not equal 0)
    LOOP2
    if (current value stored at voc index does not equal 0)
        if (value stored at cognome index is equal to value stored at voc index)
            increment cognome index
            set voc index equal to 0
            goto LOOP1
        else
            increment voc index 
            goto LOOP2
    else
        store value at address based on storage index
        increment storage index
        increment cognome index
        set voc index equal to 0
        goto LOOP1
```

With the above knowledge of how you want to attack the problem, you can implement the assembly as follows:

```
    .data 0x10010000
cognome:    .asciiz "rossi"
voc:        .asciiz "aeiou"
storage:

    .text 0x400000

    la $s0, cognome         #load starting address of "rossi"
    la $s1, voc             #load starting address of "aeiou"
    la $s2, storage         #load starting address to save desired letters
    li $t3, 0               #initialize index for cognome
    li $t4, 0               #initialize index for voc
    li $t5, 0               #initialize index for storage

loop1:   
    lbu $t1, cognome($t3)   #load value at cognome[$t3] into $t1
    beqz $t1, end           #if the value of $t1 is NULL, goto end

loop2:
    lbu $t2, voc($t4)       #load value at voc[$t4] into $t2
    beq $t1, $t2, is_vowel  #if $t1 == $t2 do not store, goto is_vowel
    addiu $t4, $t4, 1       #increment voc index
    beqz $t2, save          #if $t2 is NULL, all vowels have been checked,
                            #  and the value in $t1 is not a vowel, goto save.
    b loop2                 #Otherwise, check $t1 against the next letter in voc
                            #  by going to loop2

save:
    sb $t1, storage($t5)    #store the letter at storage[$t5]
    addiu $t5, $t5, 1       #increment the storage index
is_vowel:
    li $t4, 0                #reset the voc index
    addiu $t3, $t3, 1       #increment the cognome index
    b loop1                 #check the next letter in cognome, goto loop1

end:
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks man! You saved me!! Can I use a register to store all characters instad the memory? Just another thing: Can I save the character conversely?
If I don't, how can I choose the address where store characters? Far from cognome and voc

Comment: @Shika93, To my knowledge there is not an easy way to store the values in separate registers.  This is because you cannot index the registers in the same way as memory.  You could use a series of branches based on an index and in that branch of the code assign your char to a specific register (but I think that would get ugly).  If you use a single register, you could use bitwise operations.  As far as choosing the address in memory, you should be able to specify any available address within your data segment.  I just thought it would be easier to use a label.

Comment: Understood. Another thing: how can I say: "if t1>4 then"? An instruction like "bgt" without load "4" in a register.

Comment: It sounds like you need a good intro to MIPS.  Check this website out.  It has all the answers you are looking for. http://chortle.ccsu.edu/AssemblyTutorial/index.html